# Cannot set background color of a button to null in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I want to remove the greyish background of the button.

I made a button with a `drawableTop` attribute [image: button_image]

, tried removing the bg with this XML code in the button tag:

```
   android:background="@null"
   android:backgroundTint="@null"
```

This only affects the layout editor i.e. the color remains the same (default theme color) when run on an emulator
[image: result]
I also don't understand why is there a difference in colors between the layout editor and the actual app.

P.S. I am very new to Android Studio

Comment: `why is there a difference in colors between the layout editor and actual app` have you looked at your themes yet ?

Comment: try transparent background: android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign this button any color in XML and you want to transparent it then go to the color resource file and set that color's alpha value to 0 like this

[image]

now your buttons background is transparent if you mean this by null.